# OpenVPN client-to-client, участвует ли сервер

Tags: openvpn

Здравствуйте.

У меня парк из 9 серверов, самый нагруженный в плане трафика получается тот, на котором стоит nginx. При установке VPN именно на этот сервер я и накатил непосредственно OpenVPN Server, исходя из того, что он главный. В конфигурации сервера прописан параметр client-to-client.

Спустя несколько дней встал вопрос - когда сервер №4 общается с сервером №5 через VPN, они пропускают свои запросы через сервер или общаются напрямую? Дело в том, что у главного сервера и без того трафик гоняется больше чем надо, и если теперь ещё и вся система общается через него - возможно стоит перенести OpenVPN Server на какую-то другую машину внутри сети, что бы немного снизить нагрузку с главного сервера.

Вопрос - клиенты в OpenVPN общаются напрямую или через сервер?

Спасибо за ответы :)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Разобрался и перепроверил, сервер участвует как прокси между серверами в сети VPN.